# Using the commutativity of the AND operator in Coq

Tags: coq

I’m trying to prove something in Coq using the commutativity of the logic AND operator. I coded this short example:

```
Axiom ax1 : A /\ B.
Theorem th1 : B /\ A.
Proof.
  pose proof (ax1) as H.
  symmetry.
  apply H.
Qed.
```

I use axiom (ax1) in my proof, and I get stuck on the symmetry command. This is my current goal:

```
1 subgoal
H : A /\ B
______________________________________(1/1)
B /\ A
```

When I use the symmetry command, I get the following error:

```
Tactic failure:  The relation and is not a declared symmetric relation. Maybe you need to require the Coq.Classes.RelationClasses library.
```

My current solution is to destruct hypothesis H, split the goal, and apply the right sub-hypothesis to the right subgoal. It takes a lot of space and is a bit frustrating to not be able to use AND commutativity.

So I’ve some questions: is symmetry the right command to use with a commutative relation? If yes, how can I fix my code for it to work? If not, is there a way to use the commutativity of the AND operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [symmetry](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proofs/writing-proofs/equality.html?highlight=symmetry#coq:tacn.symmetry) tactic is specifically for reasoning about equalities (`a = b iff b = a`).

I don't know of general machinery for commutative operators, but you can find the lemma you need with something like this:

```
Search _ (?a /\ ?b <-> ?b /\ ?a)
```

(I cheated: originally, I used `->` and only switched to `<->` when that didn't find anything!)

There's exactly one lemma of this form in the base library and it's called `and_comm`. You should be able to solve your remaining proof obligation with it: `apply and_comm`.

Comment: Note that when `Search` gives no results, another option is to be less specific. For example, here `Search (_ /\ _)` would also work, at the cost of having to comb through the several hits.
Also, the `_` in the `Search` command isn't needed nowadays (IIRC it was important for SSR Search, which was deprecated in Coq 8.12 and removed in Coq 8.15).

Answer (score 4):

You can make the `symmetry` tactic work for any relation… as long as you show first that it is symmetric. This is done in the standard library for equality (which is why `symmetry` works for it out of the box), but not for `and`.
So if you want to use it, you have to do it yourself, like so:

```
Require Import RelationClasses.

Instance and_comm : Symmetric and.
Proof.
  intros A B [].
  now split.
Qed.
```

The `RelationClasses` module of the standard library declares the `Symmetric` typeclass, which is used by Coq when you call the symmetry tactic. Next we prove that `and` is indeed symmetric, and declare this as an instance of the `Symmetric` class. Once this is done, `symmetry` works as you expect it to.